# SQL Server error log growing too fast. Can't really tell what error messages are about

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, error-logging

We have a situation in our SQL Server 2008R2 installation where too many error messages are being generated. We keep getting about 100 new messages every minute.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

And this is another portion:

[image]

The problem is that I cannot understand what is really going on as the error messages aren't too helpful. Could anyone provide any pointers about what these messages are about and how I can go about troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: That looks like crash dump information, something is crashing perhaps. Do you know when this started? Can you correlate any change in the server to this point in time? Do you have any 3rd party plugins installed or made any changes to the server, updates or drivers? etc.

Comment: `ole32`, hey? Do you have code invoking [sp_OACreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oacreate-transact-sql) and friends from SQL?